# Why can't I merge these 2 dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

you just have to believe me that this is what's happening to me and it's driving me crazy

Basically, after a series of operation in Jupyter Notebook, I get a dictionary as below

```
dict1 = {'Cash': [], 'Current Liabilities': ['overpayment','loan'],'Debt': ['debt1', 'debt2'],
 'Dividends Declared': [],'Fixed Assets': [] }
```

My objective is to merge dict1 with dict2 to produce merge_dict below

```
dict2 = {'Cash': ['USD', 'CAD'], 'Debt': 'debt3'}
```

```
merge_dict = {'Cash': ['USD', 'CAD'], 'Current Liabilities': ['overpayment','loan'],'Debt': ['debt1', 'debt2', 'debt3'], 'Dividends Declared': [],'Fixed Assets': [] }
```

I successfully merge dict1 and dict2 using the code below:

```
for k,v in dict1.items():
    for u, i in dict2.items():
        if k == u:
            if type(i) is list:
                [v.append(e) for e in i]
            else:
                v.append(i)
```

What's driving me nuts is that the dictionary object I got (depicted as dict1 in this post) in Jupyter Notebook is exactly like dict1, but for some reasons, the produced output is this:

```
merge_dict = {'Cash': ['USD', 'CAD'], 'Current Liabilities': ['overpayment','loan'],'Debt': ['debt1', 'debt2', 'debt3'], 'Dividends Declared': ['USD', 'CAD'],'Fixed Assets': ['USD', 'CAD']}
```

I don't understand why 'Dividends Declared' and 'Fixed Assets' also appended the elements although they are different from dict2's keys. What's potentially wrong with the dict object I got that makes it behave differently from dict1?

Comment: why are you iterating through `merge_dict.items()` ?

Comment: Note that ``list`` has an ``.extend`` method. There is no need for an obscure ``[v.append(e) for e in i]``, just use ``v.extend(i)``.

Comment: `[v.append(e) for e in i]` this is not doing what you expect. `append` is an in-place operation and hence will return `None`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to change the variable names. They are updated now

@yatu: the code works for dict1 and dict2 in this example, though. I just don't understand why it doesn't work for my dict object in Jupyter lab which appears to be the same as dict1

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: i have tried .extend() method but the same problem still occurs. Why on earth do  'Dividends Declared' and 'Fixed Assets' also append the items when they don't match the keys from dict2?

Comment: Your code works fine!

Comment: I know in this example it works fine but it produces funny result in my notebook :( Is there a wizard who could see through the ordinary here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To merge 2 dicts by keys and accumulating values:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dict1 = {'Cash': [], 'Current Liabilities': ['overpayment', 'loan'], 'Debt': ['debt1', 'debt2'],
         'Dividends Declared': [], 'Fixed Assets': []}
dict2 = {'Cash': ['USD', 'CAD'], 'Debt': 'debt3'}

res = defaultdict(list)
for k in set(dict1) | set(dict2):  # Union of dict keys
    v1 = dict1.get(k, [])
    v2 = dict2.get(k, [])
    res[k].extend(v1 if isinstance(v1, list) else [v1])
    res[k].extend(v2 if isinstance(v2, list) else [v2])

print(dict(res))
```

The output:

```
{'Cash': ['USD', 'CAD'], 'Fixed Assets': [], 'Current Liabilities': ['overpayment', 'loan'], 'Dividends Declared': [], 'Debt': ['debt1', 'debt2', 'debt3']}
```

Comment: Yayyyy! This method solves the weird problem in my Jupyter Notebook. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Going with your approach, please find the code below:

```
for k,v in dict1.items():
    for u,i in dict2.items():
        if k==u:
            if type(i) is list:
                dict1[k].extend(i) # list is extending in list value of dict
            else:
                dict1[k].append(i) # elem is appending in list
print(dict1)

Output:
{'Cash': ['USD', 'CAD'], 'Current Liabilities': ['overpayment', 'loan'], 'Debt': ['debt1', 'debt2', 'debt3'], 'Dividends Declared': [], 'Fixed Assets': []}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, I still run into the same problem in Jupyter Notebook :) Thanks

Comment: This approach should work fine! Please check your dict initialisation and try again. It's working at my end!

Comment: It works for the example here, yes, but not for the weird dict object in my notebook. The accepted solution avoided the problem